# finding out complementary/opposite color of a given color

Tags: python

I am trying to find out the complementary color of a given color using Python. here is my code. the code returns error message telling "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'" I need a hint. In addition, there  might be a more robust code which calculates the opposite/complementary color, which I am basically looking for. your suggestions will be helpful.

```
from PIL import Image  

def complementaryColor(hex):
    """Returns complementary RGB color

    Example:
    >>>complementaryColor('FFFFFF')
    '000000'
    """
    if hex[0] == '#':
        hex = hex[1:]
    rgb = (hex[0:2], hex[2:4], hex[4:6])
    comp = ['02%X' % (255 - int(a, 16)) for a in rgb]
    return comp.join()
```

***another similar function***

```
def blackwhite(my_hex):
    """Returns complementary RGB color

    Example:
    >>>complementaryColor('FFFFFF')
    '000000'
    """
    if my_hex[0] == '#':
        my_hex = my_hex[1:]
    rgb = (my_hex[0:2], my_hex[2:4], my_hex[4:6])
    comp = ['%X' % (0 if (15 - int(a, 16)) <= 7 else 15) for a in rgb]
    return ''.join(comp)


print blackwhite('#36190D')
```

Comment: You meant `' '.join(comp)`?

Comment: I would change the Hex color into Hue-Saturation-Lightness - HSL. Find the complementary (opposite) Hue degree and convert it to Hex.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, ','.join(comp) overcomes the error message, but it output bizarre color codes.

Comment: one-liner: `"#%06X" % (int(my_hex.lstrip('#'), 16) ^ 0xffffff)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `join` and *formatting* needed a fix. Lists do not have a `join` method, strings do:

```
def complementaryColor(my_hex):
    """Returns complementary RGB color

    Example:
    >>>complementaryColor('FFFFFF')
    '000000'
    """
    if my_hex[0] == '#':
        my_hex = my_hex[1:]
    rgb = (my_hex[0:2], my_hex[2:4], my_hex[4:6])
    comp = ['%02X' % (255 - int(a, 16)) for a in rgb]
    return ''.join(comp)
```

The formatting for hex shoud be `%02X` for two hex characters and not `'02%X'`. The later only appends a leading `02` to a *mangled* output of 3 characters instead of 6.

---

`hex` is builtin function, so you may consider changing the name to, say `my_hex` to avoid shadowing the original `hex` function.

Comment: it works now as expected; can the code be tweaked to output only either white or black color based on a color input?

Comment: Yes, with *thresholding*. If the output of `(255 - int(a, 16))` is less than the threshold of say 127, set to 0 otherwise 255. But then for correct bitwise switching, use `comp = ['%X' % (0 if (15 - int(a, 16)) <= 7 else 15) for a in my_hex]`

Comment: got it ... I have posted your last function as blackwhite, but it does not return expected output for hex #36190D it should return white but it is returning black ... can you please take a look ... please

Comment: @AnayBose That returns `FFF0F0` which is not *whitish* ? Then you can drop inversion. `(0 if int(a, 16) <= 7 else 15)`.