# Python- Is there a function or formula to find the complementary colour of a rgb code?

Tags: python, colors, rgb, python-3.5

I have tried to find a good formula in Python 3 to calculate the complementary colour of a rgb code eg. complementary of a = b. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478409/finding-out-complementary-opposite-color-of-a-given-color

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's how to calculate the complement of an RGB colour directly. It gives the same results as the algorithm using  `colorsys` as shown in Iva Klass's answer, but in my tests it's about 50% faster. Note that it works for any RGB scheme, it doesn't matter whether the RGB components are integers or floats (as long as each component uses the same range!).

The function `hilo` implements a simple [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) to sort the RGB components.

```
# Sum of the min & max of (a, b, c)
def hilo(a, b, c):
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    if b < a: a, b = b, a
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    return a + c

def complement(r, g, b):
    k = hilo(r, g, b)
    return tuple(k - u for u in (r, g, b))
```

---

Here's a short demo, using PIL / Pillow.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Complement the colours in a RGB image 

    Written by PM 2Ring 2016.10.08
'''

import sys
from PIL import Image

# Sum of the min & max of (a, b, c)
def hilo(a, b, c):
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    if b < a: a, b = b, a
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    return a + c

def complement(r, g, b):
    k = hilo(r, g, b)
    return tuple(k - u for u in (r, g, b))

def complement_image(iname, oname):
    print('Loading', iname)
    img = Image.open(iname)
    #img.show()

    size = img.size
    mode = img.mode
    in_data = img.getdata()

    print('Complementing...')
    out_img = Image.new(mode, size)
    out_img.putdata([complement(*rgb) for rgb in in_data])
    out_img.show()
    out_img.save(oname)
    print('Saved to', oname)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        complement_image(*sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        fmt = 'Complement colours.\nUsage: {} input_image output_image'
        print(fmt.format(sys.argv[0]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Input image

[image: source image]

#### Output image

[image: output image]

---

Here's a Numpy version of `complement_image`. On my machine it processes the "Glasses" image about 3.7 times faster than the previous version.

```
import numpy as np

def complement_image(iname, oname):
    print('Loading', iname)
    img = Image.open(iname)
    #img.show()

    in_data = np.asarray(img)
    #print(in_data.shape)

    print('Complementing...')
    lo = np.amin(in_data, axis=2, keepdims=True)
    hi = np.amax(in_data, axis=2, keepdims=True)
    out_data = (lo + hi) - in_data

    out_img = Image.fromarray(out_data)
    #out_img.show()
    out_img.save(oname)
    print('Saved to', oname)
```

---

Here's a brief demo using  [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org) (and Numpy) to create complementary colours in the more perceptually uniform CIELuv colourspace.

```
from skimage.color import rgb2luv, luv2rgb
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

luv_data = rgb2luv(in_data) * (1, -1, -1)
out_data = img_as_ubyte(luv2rgb(luv_data))
```

[image: CIELuv complement]

Comment: I noticed that, according to the picture, that the complimentary of green is purple. However, if you look at any colour wheel you'll see that the complimentary of green is red and the complimentary of purple is yellow. How come this has happened in the picture?

Comment: @BillReason The traditional colour wheel of artists has the complements you mention, but the modern [RGB colour wheel](http://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/) has green opposite purple. Wikipedia has a traditional colour star next to an RGB one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors#Colors_produced_by_light).

Comment: (cont) However, the RGB colour space is not perceptually uniform, and RGB complements are by no means faithful to human vision. You can get better complements from a [CIELUV diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELUV#/media/File:CIE_1976_UCS.png). In that diagram, treat the white point near the top centre of the diagram as the centre of a circle, then complementary colours are diametrically opposite each other on that circle. Modern colour theory is rather complex, and I freely admit that I'm no expert. :)

Comment: @BillReason Here's a great blog post by Jason Cohen on this topic: [Color Wheels are wrong? How color vision actually works](http://blog.asmartbear.com/color-wheels.html)

Comment: The "Glasses" image was created by  [Gilles Tran](http://www.oyonale.com/modeles.php?lang=en&page=40), using POV-Ray. Gilles has placed the source code for this image in the public domain.

Comment: out of curiosity, is your hilo function faster than return max(a,b,c)+min(a,b,c)

Comment: @Marc [Yes!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFkcFKxDAQhu-FvsMcEy1LVfRQ1rfwtixl2iY60CQlnYXFp3eSbYN60EIof77M_08mNgYHEf0kP3JLiJyVrHdTVzZRJmeId_omKtZVXU3GwgfNoSersIGhgVF3dQXykYURjjB0eRdeYRRe0CAIO0g1guQE_lsVDV-iB4R7GH9kO_c7ezvqyBciVQ6vRSaDlT6NJDy0bVtXcwjLWpS4I6PIkyqTUI_PL7qBv7W-NWBDBALycCMpSZ-TbQI2AbWNrdnvsPe-RPKs7KHvPTrT95sjSzN57GpGN0wyu5NVd6xzFCfH1PFZfzdZ5a3MpPgQzWKQ1VMD-Zpa6y-y0YuE&lang=python)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is ready solution for this, but there is a [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html%20%22colorsys%22%20standard%20module) module in standard library, it can help.

I think you first need to convert RGB into [HSV or HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), then "rotate" hue, and convert back to RGB, if you need. For example (I'm not sure about proper rotating):

```
from colorsys import rgb_to_hsv, hsv_to_rgb

def complementary(r, g, b):
   """returns RGB components of complementary color"""
   hsv = rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)
   return hsv_to_rgb((hsv[0] + 0.5) % 1, hsv[1], hsv[2])
```

Comment: Although this might not be "faster" under some runtime conditions in python, up voted for the lack of code.  I consider this "the" answer when you need to generate the opposite color in a one-off scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
r,g,b = [25,25,25]

def get_complementary(color):
    color = color[1:]
    color = int(color, 16)
    comp_color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color
    comp_color = "#%06X" % comp_color
    return comp_color
hex_val = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (r,g,b)
h = get_complementary(hex_val)
print("Complementary color",h)
h = h.lstrip('#')
print('RGB =', tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)))
```

> ### output:
>
> #### Complementary color #E6E6E6
>
> #### RGB = (230, 230, 230)

Comment: This method also inverts the brightness of the colours, creating a photographic negative effect. But the goal here is to preserve the brightness (and saturation) and just complement the hue.