# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'JpegImageFile' and 'float'

Tags: python, image-processing

I tried to run this code it's showing error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\test1.py", line 13, in <module>
    img_tinted = img * [1, 0.95, 0.9]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'JpegImageFile' and 'float'
```

Here Img_tinted is supposed to change the RGB ratio of the picture.

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave, imresize

# Read an JPEG image into a numpy array
img = imread('assets/cat.jpg')
print(img.dtype, img.shape)  # Prints "uint8 (400, 248, 3)"

img_tinted = img * [1, 0.95, 0.9]

# Resize the tinted image to be 300 by 300 pixels.
img_tinted = imresize(img_tinted, (300, 300))

# Write the tinted image back to disk
imsave('assets/cat_tinted.jpg', img_tinted)
```

Comment: Okay, but what did you intend the code to do? Getting rid of the error is easy - just delete the offending line of code. _Fixing_ the error is more difficult, and can't be done if you don't tell us anything about the purpose of your code.

Comment: I am learning image processing and this is a basic code which I wanted to run. The purpose is to resize the image and tint it a little bit.

Comment: So `img * [1, 0.95, 0.9]` is supposed to multiply the red channel by 1, the green channel by 0.95 and the blue channel by 0.9? You should [edit] that information into the question, by the way.

Comment: Done. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: Maybe, but only after you answer my question...

Comment: I have told you the purpose of the code and that statement to what are the other questions?

Comment: I still don't know what `img * [1, 0.95, 0.9]` is supposed to do. I have a guess, but you haven't confirmed it.

Comment: You were right. It is there to change the RGB ratio of the picture.

Comment: Try `img[:,:,1] *= 0.95` and `img[:,:,2] *= 0.9`.

Comment: IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: How about `img = (img * np.array([1, 0.95, 0.9])).astype('uint8')`?

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing as what you're trying to do, but you can get an idea of how to split the image into r,g,b channels and do operations on the channels from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42874813/1222951)

Comment: Did you read this `imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead.` from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html)?

Comment: `img_tinted = img * [1, 0.95, 0.9]` works for me.. .. What do you get for `type(img)` just after you read/create it?