# Number of channels in pil (pillow) image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to find a way to get the number of channels of an image using Pillow. This seems rather trivial but I couldn't find it (the simple answer).

I know I can work it around with a minor overhead like (2 possibilities thought):

- Convert to numpy and check `array.shape`
- Check `image.size[0]*image.size[1]` against `len(image.getdata())`

so I am not really interested in finding a working solution but rather in accomplishing this using pillow.

The code I am using is straight forward:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(image_path)
image.size  # <- this gives the size of the image but not the channel as in numpy.
```

> (609, 439)

I also found this approach inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872779/3584765) (which also imports overhead of course):

```
num_channel = len(image.split())
```

To me it seems really peculiar I cannot find this simple answer.

Comment: have you try `image.mode`? `Image` also have `image.info` & `Image.getbands()`

Comment: So, maybe the simpler way would be to use `image.mode` I guess. `image.info` is not standardized and `getbands()` also seems a work around.

Comment: There is an attribute called layers (image.layers). But it seems that if you open a png image, 3 layers are assumed and this value is not set... Not sure if this is enough for you

Comment: Most of the time I find myself just converting to the number of channels I want, so if I want RGB but the image may be a single-channel palette image, I just use `im = Image.open('...').convert('RGB')` What do you want the number of channels for, by the way?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question (although I basically will sum up the comment of @cryptonome).

Well, when it comes to PIL the options as I get it are:

- `image.mode`: returns a str containing the mode of the data read. Typical values are `"RGB"` and `"L"` for RGB and gray-scale images respectively. Modes are presented [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes).
- `im2.info`: which returns a dict containing various information about the image. This is image format specific. For jpg images for example it (possibly) contains fields with keys:
  `dpi`, `jfif`, `jfif_density`, `exif` etc. More information about *jpg* images can be found [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg).
- `image.getbands()`: which returns a tuple (even a 1 element one) containing all different channel present in the data. For a typical RGB image this would be `('R', 'G', 'B')` and for a typical gray-scale image would be `('L',)`.

So, judging from the above the more concise method in my opinion would be to compare `image.mode` against `L` and `RGB` strings to find if an image is gray-scale or not or if the number of channels (as in this question) is the main question then a simple `len(image.getbands())` would do the job.

Normally `len(image.mode)` will coincide with `len(image.getbands())` and could be used in its place but since there is at least one mode `YCbCr` which contains 5 characters but only 3 channels (3x8-bit pixels, color video format) it's safer to use `len(image.getbands())` I guess.