# How do I fix this image shape error when feeding image to ResNet50?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet, image-classification

I would like to use a camera attached to a Raspberry Pi 4 to stream video and detect objects simultaneously. I have been able to take photos and record videos using this apparatus.

However, when I try to run a ResNet50 classifier on top of the stream, I am facing a shape inconsistency error.

I request you to help me find the line number where the problem might be originating from.

The error and the code (relatively simple) are attached below.

Error:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "resnet50" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 1, 224, 224)`

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import CircularOutput
from PIL import Image

# Define the resolution for the low-resolution video stream
lsize = (320, 240)

# Load a pre-trained TensorFlow model
classifier = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

# Initialize the Picamera2
picam2 = Picamera2()

# Configure the video settings
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration(
    main={"size": (1920, 1080), "format": "RGB888"},
    lores={"size": lsize, "format": "YUV420"}
)
picam2.configure(video_config)

# Initialize the H.264 encoder for video capture
encoder = H264Encoder(2000000, repeat=True)
encoder.output = CircularOutput()
picam2.encoder = encoder

# Start the camera and the encoder
picam2.start()
picam2.start_encoder(encoder)

# Define the dimensions of the low-resolution frame
w, h = lsize

# Continuous loop to capture and process frames
while True:
    # Capture a frame from the low-resolution stream
    cur = picam2.capture_buffer("lores")

    # Convert the frame to an image and
    # preprocess it for the deep learning model
    image = Image.fromarray(cur.astype('uint8'))
    image = image.resize((224, 224))  # Resize to match the model's input size
    image = np.array(image) / 255.0  # Normalize
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension

    # Run the deep learning model on the frame
    predictions = classifier.predict(np.expand_dims(image, axis=-1))

    # Print the model's predictions (customize as needed)
    print(
        "Model predictions class:",
        tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(
            preds=predictions
        )
    )
    time.sleep(1)

# Stop the camera and the encoder
picam2.stop()
picam2.stop_encoder()
```

Comment: `image = image.resize((224, 224))  # Resize to match the model's input size`, this is not the input shape of the model, you are missing the channel dimension here which is 3 (as expected by the model).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/status_lights/mnv2.py", line 59, in <module>
    image = image.resize((224, 224, 3))  # Resize to match the model's input size
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1935, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: argument 1 must be sequence of length 2, not 3

Comment: You cannot change the shape of a `PIL` image that way. `PIL` doesn't keep the [channel dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880997), the way `numpy` arrays do. Can you check the type of `cur` and if it's an array which I guess it is, can you check it's shape?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, Ro.oT. I was able to fix this error and get the ResNet50 to work.

Comment: No worries, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I changed `lsize` to `(160, 120)`,

```
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration(
    main={"size": (224, 224), "format": "RGB888"},
    lores={"size": lsize, "format": "YUV420"}
)
```

, and

```
    image = Image.fromarray(cur.astype('uint8'))
    image = np.array(image)
    image = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image)
```

Working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import CircularOutput
from PIL import Image

# Define the resolution for the low-resolution video stream
lsize = (160, 120)

# Load a pre-trained TensorFlow model
classifier = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

# Initialize the Picamera2
picam2 = Picamera2()

# Configure the video settings
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration(
    main={"size": (224, 224), "format": "RGB888"},
    lores={"size": lsize, "format": "YUV420"}
)
picam2.configure(video_config)

# Initialize the H.264 encoder for video capture
encoder = H264Encoder(2000000, repeat=True)
encoder.output = CircularOutput()
picam2.encoder = encoder

# Start the camera and the encoder
picam2.start()
picam2.start_encoder(encoder)

# Define the dimensions of the low-resolution frame
w, h = lsize

# Continuous loop to capture and process frames
while True:
    # Capture a frame from the low-resolution stream
    cur = picam2.capture_array()

    # Convert the frame to an image and
    # preprocess it for the deep learning model
    image = Image.fromarray(cur.astype('uint8'))
    image = np.array(image)
    image = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image)

    # Expand dimensions to create a batch of size 1
    image = image[None, ...]

    # Run the deep learning model on the frame
    predictions = classifier.predict(image)

    # Print the model's predictions (customize as needed)
    print(
        "Model predictions class:",
        tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(
            preds=predictions
        )
    )
    time.sleep(1)

# Stop the camera and the encoder
picam2.stop()
picam2.stop_encoder()
```

PS: Special thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/12317368/ro-ot.